# Unlock JButton as fields have text

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, enable-if

As the topic suggests I want to unlock(setEnabled(true)) my JButton register when the other fields have any text but I don't know what type of listener is this. I upload an image for clearer understanding. http://postimg.org/image/ab8alz44d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a document listener for each text field.

```
void init() {
  //construct text fields
  ...
  // add listeners
  textField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      checkUnlock();
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      checkUnlock();
    } 
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      checkUnlock();
    });

   // repeat for each textfield
}
...
private void checkUnlock() {
  boolean unlock = !(textField1.getText().equals("")) && !(textField2.getText().equals("")); // ... and so on
  yourButton.setEnabled(unlock);
}
```

Comment: 1+ for the DocumentListener

Comment: `when the other fields have any text` - is a "space" considered text? This will complicate the if condition as more text fields are used.

Comment: If it is not considered text what would you suggest? This solution might work: string != null && !string.isEmpty() && !string.trim().isEmpty();

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic and reusable implementation of using a `DocumentListener` to handle this. You can related 1 or more text fields to a specific button. The button will only be enable when all the text fields have some text:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DataEntered implements DocumentListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    public DataEntered(JButton button)
    {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void addTextField(JTextField textField)
    {
        textFields.add( textField );
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    }

    public boolean isDataEntered()
    {
        for (JTextField textField : textFields)
        {
            if (textField.getText().trim().length() == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    private void checkData()
    {
        button.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JButton submit = new JButton( "Submit" );
        submit.setEnabled( false );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

        DataEntered de = new DataEntered( submit );
        de.addTextField( textField1 );
        de.addTextField( textField2 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add key listener to text fields and check all fields have some values, if so then enable jbutton.

```
text1.addKeyListener(this);
text2.addKeyListener(this);
```

And in key typed method write

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
if(text1.getText().length() > 0 && text2.getText().length() > 0) {
button.setEnabled(true);
} else { button.setEnabled(false); }
}
```

Comment: 1-, Don't use a KeyListener. Swing has newer an better API's to handle this. Also, when posting code follow Java conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. It should be "public" not "Public". There is no `onKeyTyped(...)` method in a KeyListener, I think you mean "keyTyped". What happens if the delete key is pressed, no keyTyped event will be generated and the text field could now be empty which means you need to disable the button.

Comment: Removed the down vote, but I still can't recommend the answer since a KeyListener is not the best solution.